# How to extract similar blocks of code from multiple files into a single file?

Tags: search, pattern-matching

**Problem:**

I have multiple large files that contain the following code block(s) split across all of them:

```
type Query {
 ...
}

extend type Query {
 ...
}

extend type Query {
 ...
}
```

I wish to parse all files and extract this `Query` block and have it merged into a single file.
The code between the `Query` blocks and number of lines differs from one file to the next. And there could be different blocks before/after the `Query` blocks - all demarcated with `{}`.

I understand simple regexes will not work since they could skip over a closing brace and match the entire file instead.

Other than writing a program to read the file line-by-line are there other UNIX-y ways of solving this problem? My guess is what I want to do is "structural match" and that implies something like a CFG (context-free-grammar) parsing and may signal to something like YACC. Although I'm not sure if there's an easier solution and how to go about it.